# How to wire light switch passthrough

Tags: light-fixture

I've swapped a 2-gang switch for a simple 1-way switch to control the ceiling lights. Previously the room had wall lights on the 2nd gang which I've now removed. In doing so, the light in the next room is also disconnected.
[image]
My question is, from the attached picture, what would I need to do to effect a passthrough whilst maintaining the present switch?

Comment: How was it connected before?

Comment: In particular, where's the remaining black wire? I count 4 reds, but 3 blacks...

Comment: Unfortunately I lost the photo of the original wiring. And yes there's only one black on the right somehow.

Comment: Are there any other switch locations that controlled the wall lights in question?

Comment: thanks for replying, no it was just this double gang with left switch controlling two ceiling lights & right switch controlling 3 wall lights, no other switches